# Completeness in a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

To prove that a Banach space $\mathcal B$ is complete, one should show that every Cauchy sequence converges i.e.
$$(x_n)_n\in \mathcal B:$$
$$\forall e>0\ \exists N \ \forall n,m>N \ \|x_n-x_m\|<e$$
$$\implies \ \exists x \ \in \mathcal B \ \forall e \ \exists n\ \|x-x_n\|<e$$
However I found some books which, to show that $\mathcal B=(C^0,\|•\|_\infty)$ is complete, assume that there is a function $f$ s.t.
$\|f_n-f\|_\infty \to 0$
and only show that $f$ Is continous. Is there a therem which allows to do that?

Comment: Do you mean a normed vector space? Banach spaces are complete by definition, so there is no need to show that they are complete. When you see proofs that $C^0$ (presumably when the domain is compact...) equipped with the $\sup$-norm is complete, the aim is to show it is a Banach space. (The fact that it is a normed vector space is usually obvious.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's being used here is that the space of all *bounded* functions on a set $X$ is complete under the uniform norm.  Of course, this still requires proof.  The idea is that if the sequence $f_n$ is Cauchy in uniform norm, then it is pointwise Cauchy, i.e. for every $x$ the sequence of real numbers $f_n(x)$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$.  Therefore it converges to a limit, and we set $f(x)$ to be this limit.  Thus $f_n \to f$ pointwise, and then one has to check that $f_n$ indeed converges uniformly to $f$.

Once this is established, then it is indeed enough to verify that if all the $f_n$ are continuous, then so is $f$.